# Turn off fancyhdr auto-spacing

Tags: fancyhdr

Fancyhdr gives me warnings that my header height is too small, and is adding extra space at the top of some of my pages. How do I turn this off?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{32pt}
\lhead{-}
\rhead{-}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\the\headheight
\pagebreak
\section{}
\the\headheight

\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the head height yourself: `\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}` instead of `0pt`.

Comment: I prefer a head height of 0pt, and, though fancyhdr likes complaining, this doesn't cause an issue.

Comment: You need to load `geometry`, by the way. Or otherwise set the page correctly. (Otherwise the `a4paper` won't work correctly.) There is no reason to override `fancyhdr` here. Set `\headheight` as it wants and adjust another dimension to compensate. That height is not independently visible in the output, so it makes no odds.

Comment: fancyhdr does not reset your `headheight` it ask you to do. You can see by typing `\the\headheight` or  check the log file with`\showthe\headheight`

Comment: The package is not adding any space it is just warning you that your settings are incorrect, you are specifying a heading but not leaving space for it. If you don't want to fix that then like any tex you could redefine some commands to remove the error check, but why would you do that?

Comment: Based on the minimal working example, the package does appear to be adding space (\the\headheight produces 12.0pt on the second page)

Comment: Ok, you're right and I am sorry. You can try `\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\def\@fancyvbox#1#2{\vbox{#2}}
\makeatother`

Comment: Interspersing \setlength{\headheight}{0pt} throughout the document (so that there's one on every page) fixes the header, but this is not a satisfactory solution