# Use smaller \headheight in fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

When I use headers without `fancyhdr`, TeX is happy to use the same `\headheight` as is used for the text, but when I use `fancyhdr`, `fancyhdr` increases `\headheight`.

Here is an MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,left=0.75in,right=1.00in,
            top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Book}
\author{Henry Elliott}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This warning is given by pdflatex:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 13.59999pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

If possible, how can I keep the \headheight as it is without `fancyhdr` when using `fancyhdr`?

Comment: please see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271159/turn-off-fancyhdr-auto-spacing

Comment: I can `\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}` as suggested or even `\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}`, but this has no effect.

Comment: my last comment there: `\usepackage{fancyhdr} \makeatletter \def\@fancyvbox#1#2{\vbox{#2}} \makeatother`

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to maintain my original top margin.

Comment: another solution `\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,left=0.75in,right=1.00in,
            top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,
            includehead]{geometry}` now the header height is part from text height

Comment: why would you expect setting it to 12pt or 0pt to remove the warning when the warning says it has to be at least 13.6pt?

Comment: My concern is that the introduction of the `fancyhdr` package changes my top margin for text. It is possible that `\headheight` is a red herring.

Comment: that's because of the bad settings given to geometry. `\topmargin` is 24pt initially, after geometry tries to match the size given `\topmargin` is `-13.80629pt` not really possible to maintain an even baseline space with a negative margin, you give fancyhdr a hard time.